# Why was Jeanne d'Arc killed?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

In 16's files in Assassin's Creed 2 it indicates that Jeanne d'Arc was killed because she had the Piece of Eden: Sword.

I am unsure if the Templars knew that Jeanne d'Arc had a Piece of Eden so I am wondering, did the Templars manipulate events to see her killed for the sole purpose of getting the Sword or did someone see what the Sword did and believed it was witchcraft and the Templars  only learned the Sword was a Piece of Eden after her death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this unofficial wiki](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Jeanne_d%27Arc):

> Jeanne was captured by English troops, accused of witchery, and burned at the stake on May 31 1431, at the age of 19. However, the Templar Order had orchestrated her execution in order to steal her Sword.
>
> An ancestor of Warren Vidic was present at the trial and execution.

Since the Templars apparently orchestrated her execution, it is very likely they already knew about the Sword beforehand.